# Writing jQuery callbacks for ajax requests

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I've three ajax requests. The 2nd one can be fired only after the first one and the third one can be fired after the 2nd one.

Currently, I'm writing all the three ajax requests together.

```
$("#button-1").click(function() {
    $.ajax({
        //something
        success: function(response) {
             $("#content").html(response); 
        },
    });
});
$("#content").ready(function(){
$("#button-2").click(function() {
    $.ajax({
        //something
    });
});});
$("#content").ready(function(){
$("#button-3").click(function() {
    $.ajax({
        //something
    });
});});
```

How could I better structure my js code above using callbacks and encapsulating each ajax request into a separate function?
I've looked at a lot of SO posts but unable to find a reliable method. It would be good even if one could post any tutorials/blogs/SO posts.

Comment: so if you click button 3 before button 1 then the ajax request should not be fired

Comment: @ArunPJohny: Yes, it couldn't be fired. 3rd request could be fired only after the 2nd response has returned.

Comment: Use a library which does it for you. caolan/async and kriskowal/q comes to mind.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IMHO, they way to do is to delay the event handler registration for button2 and button3 like

```
jQuery(function () {
    function ajax1() {
        return $.ajax({
            success: function (response) {},
        });
    }

    function ajax2() {
        return $.ajax({
            success: function (response) {},
        });
    }

    function ajax3() {
        return $.ajax({
            success: function (response) {},
        });
    }

    $("#button-1").click(function () {
        ajax1().done(function () {
            $("#button-2").click(function () {
                ajax2().done(function () {
                    $("#button-3").click(ajax3)
                })
            })
        })
    });
});
```

Update: a slightly different version

```
jQuery(function () {
    function ajax1() {
        return $.ajax({
            success: function (response) {
                //something
                $("#button-2").click(ajax2)
            }
        });
    }

    function ajax2() {
        return $.ajax({
            success: function (response) {
                //something
                $("#button-3").click(ajax3);
            }
        });
    }

    function ajax3() {
        return $.ajax({
            success: function (response) {
                //something
            }
        });
    }

    $("#button-1").click(ajax1);
});
```

Comment: Agreed. But, wouldn't it be better to get rid of nesting? To get of nesting only, I wrote the above code as separate requests.

Comment: @PalakArora you could move the done handler within the ajaxx methods if you want.... so that it won't look nested

Comment: @PalakArora Using `.click(function`, the number of calls of `ajax2` and `ajax3` for a single click will increase, according to the amount of clicks on `#button-1` and `#button-2` respectively. Here is a quick demo : http://jsfiddle.net/wared/eav8s/. I guess this is not the expected behaviour, so, if you actually need a workaround, have a look at the bottom of this answer : http://stackoverflow.com/a/19763435/1636522.

Answer (score 1):

You could do this (quite close to what you've tried) :

```
var firstClick = $.Deferred(),
    secondClick = $.Deferred();

$("#button-1").click(function () {
    $.ajax({
        //something
        success: function () {
            $("#content").html(response);
            firstClick.resolve();
        }
    });
});

firstClick.done(function () {
    $("#button-2").click(function () {
        $.ajax({
            //something
            success: function () {
                secondClick.resolve();
            }
        });
    });
});

secondClick.done(function () {
    $("#button-3").click(function () {
        $.ajax({
            //something
        });
    });
});
```

That said, I guess you should rather use `.one('click', function` instead of `.click(function` in order to prevent ajax calls to fire again.

Comment: I believe this is the right answer for what the OP is asking (how to make `click` #2 happen after `click` #1

Answer (score 0):

for example:

```
function ajaxCall(url, task, sucess, failure)
{
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: url,
        data: {task: task},
        dataType: "json",
        success: function(result){ if(success){success(result);}},
        failure: function(result){ if(failure){failure(result);}},
    });
}
```

usage:

```
ajaxCall('getData.php','getMenu',function(response) {
             $("#content").html(response); 
        },function(response){
            alert(response);
        });
```

or:

```
ajaxCall('getData.php','getContent',function(response){$("#content").html(response);});
```

Answer (score 0):

How about having a boolean variable in success callback of ajax.

```
var isFirstFired = false;
var isSecondFired = false;
```

Here is the success callback of button-1

```
$("#button-1").click(function() {
    $.ajax({
        //something
        success: function(response) {
             $("#content").html(response); 
             isFirstFired  = true;
        },
    });
});
```

Then in second button click, check it

```
if (isFirstFired) {
   $.ajax({
        //something
        isSecondFired = true;
    });
}
else {
  alert("button 1 ajax is not fired");
}
```

Similar for third button

```
if (isSecondFired ) {
   $.ajax({
        //something            
    });
}
else {
  alert("button 2 ajax is not fired");
}
```